# WPF Declare ContextMenu in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I created a style for a `ListViewItem` with a `ContextMenu` so that when I right click on a `ListViewItem` I can delete/remove it via the `ContextMenu`.

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewCheckoutColumnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="ListViewItem_ContextMenuClick"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**And my `ListView`:**

```
<ListView Name="ListViewCheckoutTable" Margin="20,20,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200" FontSize="14" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewCheckoutColumnStyle}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Sadly this code throws an error whenever I try to run it. I get an invalid cast Exception saying that it cannot convert `MenuItem` into `Grid`.

What I should also say is that my `ListView` is filled with `MenuItems`

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for me, could you show a piece of code where you add the menu items to the listview? Did you try to add the menu items directly to the grid or to the items in listview.Items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define the `ContextMenu` as a separate resource:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu" x:Shared="False">
    <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="ListViewItem_ContextMenuClick"/>
</ContextMenu>
<Style x:Key="GridViewCheckoutColumnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
</Style>
```